# When did masturbation become such a severe prohibition?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, provenance

Before the kaballah of the Arizal began to filter into Jewish thought, was ho'tza'at zerah le'vatala considered as terrible of a sin as we tend to think today? Was it considered a sin at all?

Comment: Er and Onan in the Torah

Comment: @gershon neither of them masturbated as far as we know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even before the Arizal, it was known as a serious sin. For example, the Talmud (Niddah 13b) states:

> מאי דכתיב ידיכם דמים מלאו - אלו המנאפים ביד
>
> What is the meaning of the verse: "your hands are full of blood" (Isaiah 1:15) - these are those who commit forbidden sexual acts with their hands.

Rashi (ibid) explains that this refers to masturbation.

Based on this passage, Rambam writes ([Hilkhot Issurei Biah 21](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/5121.htm):18):

> **אסור להוציא שכבת זרע לבטלה**; לפיכך לא יהיה אדם דש מבפנים וזורה מבחוץ, ולא יישא קטנה שאינה ראויה לוולד.  אבל **אלו שמנאפין ביד, ומוציאין שכבת זרע--לא דיי שהוא איסור גדול, אלא שעושה זה בנידוי הוא יושב**; **ועליהם נאמר "ידיכם, דמים מלאו" (ישעיהו א,טו), וכאילו הרגו נפש**.
>
> It is forbidden to masturbate...One who does; besides for the fact that it is a great sin, becomes excommunicated. And regarding them it is stated: "your hands are full of blood", and it is as though he committed murder.

Also noteworthy, is that even thoughts that can lead to nocturnal emissions are presented as being prohibited by Hazal (Avodah Zara 20b):

> ת"ר: ונשמרת מכל דבר רע - שלא יהרהר אדם ביום ויבוא לידי טומאה בלילה

Tosafot there understand that this is a full derasha (and thus in their view, a biblical commandment). This is also the implication of Ramban (Hullin 37b) who is in turn quoted (without citation) by Ran's commentary there. If even these thoughts are biblically forbidden, masturbation would certainly seem to be considered biblically inappropriate. Other Rishonim dispute this this is actually a biblical prohibition (e.g. Ye'reim 45).

Comment: Are there those who understand that passage in the Talmud  (niddah 13b) as not referring to masturbation? Is it the Rambam who popularized that understanding? Why is that called "ni'uf" ?

Comment: @MarkA. Woops you are right. How silly of me. I repeat that the word means different things in different contexts, cf. Yirmiyah 3:9. | `And it wouldn't be Torah prohibition based on this posuk.` It is true that this isn't evidence for a Torah prohibition. Your question dint specify anything about Torah prohibitions, so I am not sure why that is relevant. | The question was about severity, and I quotes Rambam and the Talmudic background to show that it is indeed severe.

Comment: Whose translation is that?

Answer (score 3):

The Mishna (Nida 2,  1) already mentions this issur. (And this is the only place where there is such cruel expression.)

Here you have the mishna and the Talmud on it:

**מתני': כל היד המרבה לבדוק בנשים משובחת ובאנשים תקצץ**: גמ' מ''ש נשים ומאי שנא אנשים נשים לאו בנות הרגשה נינהו משובחות אנשים דבני הרגשה נינהו תקצץ אי הכי מאי איריא מרבה כי לא מרבה נמי כי קתני מרבה אנשים   […]   גופא **ר''א אומר כל האוחז באמה ומשתין כאילו מביא מבול לעולם** אמרו לו לרבי אליעזר והלא נצוצות נתזין על רגליו ונראה ככרות שפכה ונמצא מוציא לעז על בניו שהן ממזרים אמר להן מוטב שיוציא לעז על בניו שהן ממזרים ואל יעשה עצמו רשע שעה אחת לפני המקום תניא אידך אמר להן רבי אליעזר לחכמים אפשר יעמוד אדם במקום גבוה וישתין או ישתין בעפר תיחוח **ואל יעשה עצמו רשע שעה אחת לפני המקום** הי אמר להו ברישא אילימא קמייתא אמר להו ברישא בתר ד**אמר להו איסורא** הדר אמר להו תקנתא אלא הא אמר להו ברישא ואמרו ליה אין לו מקום גבוה ועפר תיחוח מאי אמר להן מוטב שיוציא לעז על בניו ואל יעשה עצמו רשע שעה אחת לפני המקום **וכל כך למה מפני שמוציא שכבת זרע לבטלה דא''ר יוחנן כל המוציא שכבת זרע לבטלה חייב מיתה** שנאמר {בראשית לח-י} וירע בעיני ה' אשר עשה וימת גם אותו רבי יצחק ורבי אמי אמרי **כאילו שופך דמים** שנאמר {ישעיה נז-ה} הנחמים באלים תחת כל עץ רענן שוחטי הילדים בנחלים תחת סעיפי הסלעים אל תקרי שוחטי אלא סוחטי רב אסי אמר **כאילו עובד עבודת כוכבים** כתיב הכא תחת כל עץ רענן וכתיב התם {דברים יב-ב} על ההרים הרמים ותחת כל עץ רענן

Comment: What does this add to the previous answer which already cited this piece of Talmud?

Comment: @DoubleAA This is an earlier occurence. And this Talmud citation is more explicit, severe, and very long! While in the above answer it was more focused on the Rambam (see in the comments). I did not understand why not quoting the talmudic source in place...maybe too long to type?, so --thanks to the Orayta Jewish Books application! -- I copied it here. But indeed this answer should also cite these two other citations, because they give interdictions (אזהרה) while this is more axed on the punishment (עונש).